# What is Partition Table: gpt_sync_mbr?

Tags: parted

What is gpt_sync_mbr in GNU parted?

## parted /dev/vda

```
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/vda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt_sync_mbr
Disk Flags:
```

Not info found about this in http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#mklabel .

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what is known as a "[Hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html)"

Details on this partition scheme are sketchy at best... Some more detail and background can be found [here](https://github.com/rear/rear/issues/544) about a third of the way down the page, look for a posting by jsmeix that gives some history and detail about this (the thread itself it likely not relevant, but the information in that post and a few of the subsequent ones could be).